# Filtering tshark output for .csv. Preventing errors from missing fields

Tags: tshark

I am trying to filter a pcap file in tshark wit a lua script and ultimately output it to a .csv. I am most of the way there but I am still running into a few issues.

This is what I have so far

```
tshark -nr   -V -X lua_script:wireshark_dissector.lua -r myfile.pcap -T fields -e frame.time_epoch -e Something_UDP.field1 -e Something_UDP.field2 -e Something_UDP.field3 -e Something_UDP.field4 -e Something_UDP.field5 -e Something_UDP.field6 -e Something_UDP.field15 -e Something_UDP.field16 -e Something_UDP.field18 -e Something_UDP.field22 -E separator=,
```

Here is an example of what the frames look like, sort of.

```
frame 1
time: 1626806198.437893000
Something_UDP.field1: 0
Something_UDP.field2: 1
Something_UDP.field3:1
Something_UDP.field5:1
Something_UDP.field6:1

frame 2
time: 1626806198.439970000
Something_UDP.field8: 1
Something_UDP.field9: 0
Something_UDP.field13: 0
Something_UDP.field14: 0

frame 3
time: 1626806198.440052000
Something_UDP.field15: 1
Something_UDP.field16: 0
Something_UDP.field18: 1
Something_UDP.field19:1
Something_UDP.field20:1
Something_UDP.field22: 0
Something_UDP.field24: 0
```

The output I am looking for would be

```
1626806198.437893000,0,1,1,,1,1,1,,,,,
1626806198.440052000,,,,,,,,,1,0,,1,1,1,,0,0,,,,
```

That is if the frame  contains one of the fields I am looking for it will output its value followed by a comma but if that field isn't there it will output a comma. One issue is that not every frame contains info that I am interested in and I don't want them to be outputted. Part of the issue with that is that one of the fields I need is epoch time and that will be in every frame but that is only important if the other fields are there.  I could use awk or grep to do this but wondering if it can all be done inside tshark.   The other issue is that the fields being requested will com from a text file and there may be fields in the text file that don't actually exist in the pcap file and if that happens I get a "tshark: Some fields aren't valid:" error.

In short I have 2 issues.

1: I need to print data only it the fields names match but not if the only match is epoch.

2: I need it to work even if one of the fields being requested doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to print data only it the fields names match but not if the only match is epoch.

Try using a display filter that mentions all the field names in which you're interested, with an "or" separating them, such s

```
  -Y "Something_UDP.field1 or Something_UDP.field2 or Something_UDP.field3 or Something_UDP.field4 or Something_UDP.field5 or Something_UDP.field6 or Something_UDP.field15 or Something_UDP.field16 or Something_UDP.field18 or Something_UDP.field22"
```

so that only packets containing at least one of those fields will be processed.

> I need it to work even if one of the fields being requested doesn't exist.

Then you will need to construct the command line on the fly, avoiding field names that aren't valid.

One way, in a script, to test whether a field is valid is to use the [dftest](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dftest.html) command:

```
dftest Something_UDP.field1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

will exit with a status of 0 if there's a field named "Something_UDP.field1" and will exit with a status of 2 if there isn't; if the scripting language you're using can check the exit status of a command to see if it succeeds, you can use that.